# Android cursor forces application to stop

Tags: android, cursor

I'm trying to access a phone number with starting an intent which opens the contactpicker.
Everything goes fine  until I try to make a cursor.I can reveive the id of the contact but on the line the cursor is initialized  , the app stops working.

The code :

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Uri result = null ;
        switch (requestCode) {
        case 1001:
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            Set<String> keys = extras.keySet();
            Iterator<String> iterate = keys.iterator();
            while (iterate.hasNext()) {
                String key = iterate.next();
                l(key + "[" + extras.get(key) + "]");
            }
            result = data.getData();
            l( "Got a result: "+ result.toString());

            break;
        }
            String id = result.getLastPathSegment();  
            l("key:" + id) ; 
//Line with the problems  , here the app stops


            Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, new String[]{id}, null);

            if(cur.getCount() > 0) {
                while (cur.moveToNext()) {
                    String idst = cur.getString(
                                cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                String name = cur.getString(
                                cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                    //Query phone here.  Covered next
                    }
                    }
            }
    } else {

        l( "A problem occured");
    }
}
```

}

error :

```
  04-30 10:42:01.669: E/AndroidRuntime(2819): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-30 10:42:01.669: E/AndroidRuntime(2819): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1001, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.contacts/contacts/lookup/3034i335793838dba8dd3/2345 flg=0x1 (has extras) }} to activity {me.Messaging.planner/me.Messaging.planner.MyMessageActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: bind or column index out of range: handle 0xc1c560
04-30 10:42:01.669: E/AndroidRuntime(2819):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2918)
04-30 10:42:01.669: E/AndroidRuntime(2819):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:2970)
04-30 10:42:01.669: E/AndroidRuntime(2819):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:132)
04-30 10:42:01.669: E/AndroidRuntime(2819):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1068)
04-30 10:42:01.669: E/AndroidRuntime(2819):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-30 10:42:01.669: E/AndroidRuntime(2819):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
04-30 10:42:01.669: E/AndroidRuntime(2819):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4277)
04-30 10:42:01.669: E/AndroidRuntime(2819):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-30 10:42:01.669: E/AndroidRuntime(2819):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-30 10:42:01.669: E/AndroidRuntime(2819):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
04-30 10:42:01.669: E/AndroidRuntime(2819):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
04-30 10:42:01.669: E/AndroidRuntime(2819):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-30 10:42:01.669: E/AndroidRuntime(2819): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: bind or column index out of range: handle 0xc1c560
04-30 10:42:01.669: E/AndroidRuntime(2819):     at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:158)
04-30 10:42:01.669: E/AndroidRuntime(2819):     at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:114)
04-30 10:42:01.669: E/AndroidRuntime(2819):     at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.bulkQueryInternal(ContentProviderNative.java:378)
04-30 10:42:01.669: E/AndroidRuntime(2819):     at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:414)
04-30 10:42:01.669: E/AndroidRuntime(2819):     at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:264)
04-30 10:42:01.669: E/AndroidRuntime(2819):     at me.Messaging.planner.MyMessageActivity.onActivityResult(MyMessageActivity.java:252)
04-30 10:42:01.669: E/AndroidRuntime(2819):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:4108)
04-30 10:42:01.669: E/AndroidRuntime(2819):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2914)
04-30 10:42:01.669: E/AndroidRuntime(2819):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Copy the exception from `logcat` & add it to your question. Also, selection arguments (`new String[]{id}`) should always be accompanied by an actual selection, e.g. `ContactsContract.Contacts._ID + "=?"`.

Comment: Yup, the issue is that loose array of selection arguments. Add a selection, as shown in the previous comment & it should work better.

Comment: Indeed it doesn't throw that error anymore , thanks ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use

```
cur.moveToFirst()
```

before while loop.